# Beginner question : logic and set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

First post on here, and apologies for its very basic content (I don't even understand most of the questions on here) but I'm wondering if anyone can help. I'm trying to teach myself maths at the ripe old age of 47, and wanted to start quite basic, with a book called "Advanced precalculus" by Daniel Kim. I liked the proposed approach, which is more theoretical and proof based than any of the other precalculus stuff I've come across (which I have gone through before, but it never seems to stick as the books never explain *why* stuff works).

I've stumbled across something that's got be stumped though. One of the problems right at the start asks the reader to evaluate the truth of falsity of $A \subseteq B \cup C \to A \subseteq B \lor A \subseteq C$

I looked at this and doodled a Venn diagram and concluded that it had to be false, since I can find an example of a set A that is a subset of the union of B and C but is not a subset of either (e.g. A={4,5,6}; B={3,4,5}; C={5,6,7}).

But the book says that the statement is true, and gives the following proof.

$A \subseteq B \cup C \to \forall x \in U, x \in A \to x \in B \cup C$

$A \subseteq B \cup C \to \forall x \in U, x \in A \to x \in A \to (x \in B \lor x \in C)$

$A \subseteq B \cup C \to \forall x \in U, x \in A \to \sim(x \in A) \lor (x \in B \lor x \in C)$

$A \subseteq B \cup C \to \forall x \in U, x \in A \to \sim(x \in A) \lor \sim(x \in A) \lor (x \in B \lor x \in C)$

$A \subseteq B \cup C \to \forall x \in U, x \in A \to (\sim(x \in A) \lor x \in B) \lor (\sim(x \in A) \lor x \in C)$

$A \subseteq B \cup C \to \forall x \in U, (x \in A \to x \in B) \lor (x \in A \to x \in C)$

$\therefore A \subseteq B \cup C \to A \subseteq B \lor A \subseteq C$

It seems to me that the existence of a counterexample (I'm doubting myself so badly I'm wondering if it even is a counterexample now) must mean there is something wrong with the proof, but I'm struggling to see what it is. I'm guessing intuitively that something goes awry around line 4 or 5 in the author's use of the Idempotent and Associative Laws. I'm thinking along the lines that for every x in U, x can be (not in A but in B), or (not in A but in C), but that does not imply that x is always in B or always in C (it can be in either) and so A does not have to be a subset of B or C.

Comment: I presume you mean $A \subseteq B \cup C \to A \subseteq B \lor A \subseteq C$?

Comment: You are right; the book is wrong.

Comment: Also, $\therefore A \subseteq A \cup\color{red}{ C} \to A \subseteq B \lor A \subseteq C$

Comment: This is very nicely postulated question.

Comment: The book's error is at the last line: it does not follow from the penultimate line.

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone Even if $B\cap C=\varnothing$, the book's claim is still wrong. Consider $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{1\}$, and $C=\{2\}$.

Comment: $\forall x [P(x) \lor Q(x)]$ does not imply $\forall x P(x) \lor \forall x Q(x)$

Comment: Problem discarded because the scope of for all x in U is not clearly indicated and statement implies statement implies statement is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

What the author appears to have done is to lift from the definition of **SET UNION**:

$$x\in A\cup B \iff x\in A \lor x\in B$$

the conclusion that this can automatically be applied to whole sets, i.e. his claim that:

$$C\subseteq A\cup B \iff C\subseteq A \lor C\subseteq B$$

which is false, as we can see if we consider:

$$ C=\{x\in A \land x\not\in B, y\in B \land y\not\in A\}$$

Then we have $C\subseteq A\cup B$ but **not** $C\subseteq A \lor C\subseteq B$.